# Does fighting from higher ground grant combat advantage?

Tags: dnd-4e, flight, combat-advantage

Proving a negative is hard. I have been reading several pages from the Rules Compendium, but information about combat advantage is very scattered.

I'm specifically interested in flying, but if it's a more general rule that applies, that's OK.

The flying speed description and the general combat advantage rules don't name it.

Answer (score 6):

**No.**

Flanking is the only “automatic” way to gain combat advantage. Other than flanking and the per-encounter Bluff check to trick an opponent (Rules Compendium page 218), the most common way to gain combat advantage is when a power explicitly grants it.

The ability of a ranged attacker to fire at a melee target who cannot otherwise strike back is already quite an advantage.